# Set Cobol method attribute property

Tags: attributes, cobol, microfocus

In Micro Focus managed Cobol, how can we set value of a method attribute?
Viz. In C# we do

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public override string[] Method
```

So in Cobol we declare the method as

```
method-id MethodName public 
     attribute OperationContractAttribute
     attribute WebGetAttribute.
```

But how do we set ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar (but not identical) to C#. The biggest difference is that the keyword 'property' has to be used before the property name.

```
method-id MethodName public 
    attribute OperationContractAttribute
    attribute WebGetAttribute(property ResponseFormat = type WebMessageFormat::Json).
```